# Перечисления в Си

Tags: c, enum

В чём основные отличия и плюсы использования перечисления в Си (enum) от обычной инициализации переменных?

Comment: В основном используются в таких случаях, когда необходимо ПЕРЕЧИСЛИТЬ например дни недели, месяцы, и вообще данные, которые могут быть обобщены одним словом и перечислены. Так гораздо читабельнее. Конечно всегда можно и через переменные, тогда можно и от ООП отказаться, все через переменные делать.
Ну и в некоторых случаях полезно воспользоваться их значениями, нумеруются по умолчанию с нуля и +1 от предыдущего.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то с точки зрения ООП и в целом программирования, правильнее использовать в некоторых случаях перечисления?

Comment: Смотри ответ ниже) Вот это я и имел в виду

Comment: Вопрос странно сформулирован. При чем здесь "инициализация переменных"? Элементы enum "переменными" не являются, поэтому не ясно, как они могут служить альтернативой для "инициализации переменных".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основное отличие заключается в первую очередь в том, что элементы `enum` в языке С являются *именованными константами* и формируют константные выражения. Альтернативным способом введения именованных констант в языке С являются макросы `#define`. Других способов нет, и никакая "инициализация переменных" вам здесь не поможет.

Вариант с `#define`, вследствие своей "макросовой" природы, является более гибким, ибо позволяет объявлять константы разных типов. `enum` позволяет объявлять константы только типа `int` (или некоего большего знакового целочисленного типа).

С другой стороны, объявления `enum`, в отличие от макросов, подчиняются общим правилам области видимости языка, что может являться несомненным преимуществом. Для локальных целей можно объявить локальный `enum`. При использовании макросов "локальность" имен приходится эмулировать вручную путем явного применения `#undef`, что весьма неудобно.

Answer (score 2):

Перечисления позволяют из всего множества целых чисел выделить именованное подмножество целочисленных констант. То есть перечисления вводят в программу некую новую абстрактную сущность. Это средство классификации констант

Сходу в голову приходит следующее.:)

Во-первых, перечисления могут использоваться как константы при задании размерностей массивов. Например,

```
enum { N = 10 };
int a[N] = { 0 };
```

Нельзя написать

```
const int N = 10;
int a[N] = { 0 };
```

Компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке, говорящее о том, что нельзя инициализировать массивы переменной длины.

Во-вторых, перечисления можно использовать как выражения в метках `case`. Например,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { Red, Green, Blue } e = Green;

    switch ( e )
    {
    case Red:
        puts( "Red" );
        break;
    case Green:
        puts( "Green" );
        break;
    case Blue:
        puts( "Blue" );
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В-третьих, использование типа перечисления в качестве типа параметра функции, является помимо лучшей читабельности еще и самодокументируемым. То есть становится ясно, с какими целочисленными значениями функция имеет дело.К тому же имена типов перечислений не конфликтуют с другими именами.

Например,

```
void draw( enum Color color );
```

Answer (score 1):

`enum` это удобные константы объединённые общей структурой.

Вы можете конечно написать

```
const int SUNDAY = 1;
const int MONDAY = 2;
```

Но enum'ы приятнее читать, код самодокументируется

```
enum Weekday{Sunday, Monday};
```

Comment: А доступ к enum может быть только в main функции или в пользовательской только? или обращаться к enum можно с любой точки программы?

Comment: зависит от того, как вы их напишите и насколько нужно инкапсулировать данное перечисление. В некоторых случаях enum'ы могут представлять собой разные понятия

Comment: `Weekday.Sunday` не компилируется...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  потому что доступ к элементам перечисления нужно делать через `::` https://godbolt.org/z/L77ecf

Comment: @Adokenai Это вам не С++. :)

Comment: Там много приколов, да, нужно создать переменную, но это скорее псевдокод было

Comment: Вопрос помечен как [С]. В C `const int` не может рассматриваться, как аналог enum. `const int` это не константа в С. Поэтому не совсем понятно, что тут делает пример с `const int`. В С аналогом enum является `#define`, а не `const int`.

Comment: @Adokenai: Что именно вы пытаетесь продемонстрировать С++ примером в вопросе по языку С?